# What does "No instance for (Comparable Integer)" mean?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```
data Set a = Set [a]
i1 = Set [1, 2, 3]
i2 = Set [3, 2, 1]

member xs x  = elem x xs
subset xs ys = and (map (member ys) xs)

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Set a) where
  (Set xs) == (Set ys) = (subset xs ys) && (subset ys xs)

class Eq a => Comparable a where
  cmp :: a -> a -> String
  cmp x y
    | x == y    = "eq"
    | otherwise = "neq"

instance Comparable a => Comparable (Set a) where
  cmp (Set xs) (Set ys)
    | (Set xs) == (Set ys) = "same"
    | otherwise            = "different"
```

When executing:  `cmp i1 i2` I get the following error:

```
No instance for (Comparable Integer) arising from a use of ‘cmp’  
 In the expression: cmp i1 i2  
 In an equation for ‘it’: it = cmp i1 i2
```

I'd like to know what it means?
Thanks.

Comment: You haven't written an `instance Comparable Integer where ....` to say how `Integer`s are `Comparable`. Since `Comparable` provides a default implementation for `cmp`, if you add the line `instance Comparable Integer` you will have a `Comparable` instance for `Integer`s.

Comment: The `Comparable` instance for a `Set a` doesn't need a `Comparable` instance for `a`. The definition of `cmp` for `Comparable (Set a)` doesn't use `cmp` from `Comparable a`, it only uses `==` from `Eq a`. The context for the `Comparable (Set a)` instance could be changed from `Comparable a =>` to `Eq a =>`.

Comment: @Cirdec I will be adding the other operators like '<', '>' to Comparable so Comparable (Set a) will eventually use cmp from Comparable a.  In the (Set a), 'a' is any type that has an ordering. Does that mean I have to add the lines "instance Comparable a" for each type a?

Comment: @User137481 The declaration `instance Comparable a => Comparable (Set a)` says that if you want to use the `Comparable` instance for a set (e.g. by calling `cmp` on it), you need to have an instance of `Comparable` for the type contained in the set. So yes.

Comment: @DanielWagner ok, so the instance declaration isn't what I want. I only want the set itself to be Comparable. The elements of the set only need to be Eq instances. So, what do I need to do to fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm still not seeing why you want `Comparable` when the Prelude already has `Ord`, which is good for any totally ordered type.

Comment: @User137481 Cirdec already said how to do that...

Comment: @dfeuer The reason is that sets are only partially ordered. For example {1, 2, 3} and {1, 5} cannot really be compared using < or >.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are executing:

```
cmp i1 i2
```

Haskell infers the type of `i1` and `i2` to be `Set [Integer]`. And since `cmp` has type:

```
cmp :: (Comparable a) => a -> a -> String
```

`Integer` has to have an instance of the `Comparable` type class; which it doesn't. So to solve this issue you should provide an instance of `Comparable` for `Integer`.

Also notice that you probably meant to use `Ord` which defines comparison between values of different types.

Comment: The elements of Set can be of any type. From your response it would mean I would have to provide an instance of Comparable for every type. I'm not sure how to do this. My intention was to make Set an instance of Comparable. The elements of the Set do not need to be instances of Comparable. Is there a solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: @User137481 Then you would have to remove `Comparable a =>` from the `Comparable (Set a)` instance.